# Custom view on status bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, facebook-messenger

Facebook Messenger shows this view for a few seconds when resuming the app (it also hides the status bar icons). Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `WindowInsets (SDK >= 20)` to get the StatusBar's height. Create a FrameLayout, apply the `LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, statusBarHeight)`. Set the layout background color to colorPrimaryDark.

Hide de Status Bar by using the method `setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`.

To add the status text, create a LinearLayout, apply the `LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)`, `Orientation = HORIZONTAL` and add a Canvas and TextView.

Finally, add the LinearLayout as the child of the FrameLayout and add the FrameLayout as the first child of the main layout.